# How to get an object from a main object

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object(mainObj) that get displayed in my console as follows

```
Object {}
 vObjects:Array[12]
 videos:Object
 __proto__:Object
```

How can I get the child (vObjects) from the mainObj so I can assign it to it's own variable?

Answer (score 3):

```
var vObjects = mainObj.vObjects;
```

Comment: I tried that but for some weird reason this gives me undefined in an angularjs controller.

Comment: I have an object mainObj. When I console log the object, I have 2 children objects. I want to get the child object of the object. I think it's a javascript possible solution so I didn't need to reference the fact that am using angularjs.

Comment: That provides no additional information over what you've already given. The answer I've given is how to reference a property of an object. Without any better description of your issue (i.e., show actual code **in your question**), that's the best answer you'll get.

Comment: @AndréDion perhaps change `mainObect` to `mainObj` in your answer to match the variable name in the question :D